# Android: non-ordered Broadcast errors with GCM

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, boot, google-cloud-messaging

I am developing an app which uses GCM. It was working fine as long as the app was invoked manually. However, I now want to set up the app to be initiated at boot-up. I have set up what I think are the proper service, broadcast receiver, and permissions to cause the app to start up at boot time. However, when I now do that, I get the following error from my existing GCM broadcast receiver:

**java.lang.RuntimeException: BroadcastReceiver trying to return result during non-ordered broadcast**

It seems like there is some sort of race condition between the GCM's broadcast receiver and the broadcast receiver I'm using as part of my app's invocation during boot-up.

... or is there a way to force GCM broadcasts to be ordered?

Has anyone seen this issue before, and if so, can you point me to docs which explain how I can resolve it?

Thank you very much.

Comment: I figured out the error. For some reason, I had put the following into my manifest for the GCM broadcast receiver: **<action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />** . Apparently, this isn't necessary, and it also causes conflicts with other on-boot intents. I removed this, and my error went away. Also, GCM still seems to start up properly on boot without this, so I don't know why I entered this, to begin with.